# SEO and traffic statistics for a business with duplicate content on multiple platforms

Tags: seo, analytics, duplicate-content, web-applications, single-page-application

I have a similar question to [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47676/seo-and-traffic-flow-for-multi-domain-web-app/47677#47677?newreg=9ac46cae92344d07ac1cdcbae5f37524). I would like to ask the person who answered it (@John Conde), to elaborate more but I can't comment as I am only new on here and don't have enough reputation so I was wondering can anybody help or elaborate on his answer.

I am building a single page phonegap application (using mainly html, css and javascript) for a company. They currently have a website getting a lot of traffic. 
Within the app I am retrieving lots of the same information to display in the app.

If the current traffic they are receiving is for example 12000 hits per month, I expect that when the app goes live some of the users (around 2000) may choose to view the content in the app instead.
This will mean their count will go down to 10000 and I would like to prevent this.

1. Is there a way I can make the app views count in their statistics?
2. Will this affect the companies google rankings?
3. What are the steps i need to take to prevent google duplicate content issues? I have added this to the app html page, in order to state the main url to be indexed. `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />` Is this the right thing to do?

Thanks for any advice